# what is worker_processes and worker_connections in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Please help me understand what `worker_processes` and `worker_connections` are in Nginx and what is the relation between them. I have looked under [Nginx directives](http://wiki.nginx.org/DirectiveIndex) it says:

`worker_processes`

> A worker process is a single-threaded process.
>
> If Nginx is doing CPU-intensive work such as SSL or gzipping and you have 2 or more CPUs/cores, then you may set worker_processes to be equal to the number of CPUs or cores.
>
> If you are serving a lot of static files and the total size of the files is bigger than the available memory, then you may increase worker_processes to fully utilize disk bandwidth.

`worker_connections`

> The worker_connections and worker_processes from the main section allows you to calculate max clients you can handle:
>
> `max clients = worker_processes * worker_connections`

So I understand that `worker_processes` is single threaded and its value is helpful in CPU-intensive work, but I am unable to understand "allows you to handle max clients you can handle".

If anyone can give an example as given in `worker_processes` it would be helpful for me to understand.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

worker_connections is the number of simultaneous connections; so they are simply stating how to calculate, for example:

- you are only running 1 process with 512 connections, you will only be able to serve 512 clients.
- If 2 processes with 512 connections each, you will be able to handle 2x512=1024 clients.

*The number of connections is limited by the maximum number of open files (RLIMIT_NOFILE) on your system*
[nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections)
has a better, updated description of worker connections.

*fyi, the wiki section is considered obsolete (dont ask), now only the main nginx.org/en/docs are preferred...*

Comment: If I have the 1GB RAM with 1CPU, what would be the ideal connections and processors ?

Comment: I think it's important to note here that according to [NGINX documenation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections), worker_connections is the maximum number of simultaneous connections a worker can open, be this to clients or to backend servers (in case of proxying).  
So if you are using nginx as a reverse proxy, the result of worker_processes * worker_connections is **not** necessarily the number of clients you can serve.

Answer (score 32):

- Worker processes:

  - Nginx worker process that handles the incoming request.
  - Set this to `worker_process auto;` to automatically adjust the number of Nginx worker processes based on available cores.
  - This can go beyond the available cores if you have IO access.
- Worker connections:

  - Each worker process can open by default 512 connections.
  - You can change this limit by `worker_connections <no>`.
  - You can set this to max limit `ulimit -n`.
  - hence,

  `max_clients = worker processes * worker connections`

Answer (score 11):

From [Nginx's  Beginner’s Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)

> nginx has one master process and several worker processes. The main
>   purpose of the master process is to read and evaluate configuration,
>   and maintain worker processes. Worker processes do actual processing
>   of requests. nginx employs event-based model and OS-dependent
>   mechanisms to efficiently distribute requests among worker processes.
>   The number of worker processes is defined in the configuration file
>   and may be fixed for a given configuration or automatically adjusted
>   to the number of available CPU cores

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it from Process and thread perspective.
Worker_process is equivalent to process and
worker_connection is equivalent to thread.

So a process(Worker_process) can have n number of threads(worker_connections).