431 Request Header Fields Too Large
I am getting the following error while calling a rest endpoint with the following nginx configuration:
# inspired by
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329261/running-nginx-as-non-root-user
# https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-behind-nginx
# https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/

error_log stderr;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109769
worker_rlimit_nofile 2048;

events {
  # max simultaneous connections
  # see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23393113
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  access_log stdout;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
  proxy_buffers
  server {
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    listen            8443 ssl;
    proxy_buffers 4 16k;
    ssl_certificate     /app/tls/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/tls/key.pem;

    # Set a number of log, temp and cache file options that will otherwise
    # default to restricted locations accessible only to root.
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_body;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      # prevent connection between nginx and uvicorn from being closed
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
  }

  upstream uvicorn {
    server 127.0.0.1:8090;
    keepalive 2;
  }

}


Headers are 31.42 KB sized so, I thing   large_client_header_buffers 4 16k; should be enough. We are using uvicorn==0.26.0 and fastapi==0.110.0. Does anyone know why is it happening?
